# How to upload multiple images in laravel so I can get them in frontend?

Tags: laravel

I want to do multiple image uploads in my laravel but so far i get errors like image must be image ... is chaos really ... help please???

```
   public function store(Request $request) {
          $request->validate([
              'name' => 'required',
              'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg|max:2048',
              'image.*' => 'image',
              'description' => 'required',
              'quantity' => 'required',
             ]);


         $imgData = [];
         if($request->hasfile('image')) {
            foreach($request->file('image') as $file)
            {
                $path = '/images/phones';
                $date = Carbon::now();
                $tempName = env('APP_URL') . '/storage' . $path . '/'. $date->year.'/' . time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $filename = time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $filePath = $path . "/$date->year";
                $file->storeAs( $filePath, $filename, 'public');
                $imgData[] = $tempName;  
            }

            $phones = new Phone;
            $phones->name = $request->name;
            $phones->description = $request->description;
            $phones->quantity = $request->quantity;
            $phones->price = $request->price;
            $phones->brand_id =$request->brand_id;
            $phones->image = json_encode($imgData);
            $phones->save();
         
            return redirect()->route('phones.index')
                            ->with('success','Product has been created successfully.');
       }
```

So far I get this error that image must be image and another error is  displaying required extensions!!

Comment: On client side You should use formData to send your request to server because You have in the same form binary data (file) mixed with other data like string or anything. Regular form doesn't support sending binary with other data types.